# Can't extract multiple elements from a Python list

Tags: python, list, slice

I have a list:

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

It's ok with slicing:`list1[2:4]`
But not with :`list1[[2,3]]`
There would be an error: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list

I can't see the difference between those 2 lines, why can't lists be used as a indices, is there anything about vectorization?
Thanks!

Comment: Please describe what you expected to happen if you use a list as index

Comment: I thought a list could be a combination of multiple separate indices, so I can get the third and fourth element out of list1

Comment: Like what we do in a numpy array np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])[[1,3,5]]

Comment: Well. numpy is numpy. built-in list is built-in list. Yes numpy.array can do what list can not. It's just how it works. In most languages you can't index a list (or array) with a negative index, but in python you can. Some interfaces are more feature-rich and others are more minimalistic. It's just how it works.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is clear, "list indices must be integers or slices, not a list".

This is a list:  `[2, 3]`
This is an integer: `2`
You can *programmatically* make a [slice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) with `slice(2, 3)`, e.g. `list1[slice(2, 3)]`.

If you have the *(optional)start/stop/(optional)step* indices in a list, you can use argument expansion, which passes the contents of an iterable as if they were separate arguments:

```py
>>> list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>> list1[2]  # integer
'c'
>>> list1[2:3]  # slice
['c']
>>> list1[slice(2,3)]  # also slice
['c']
>>> args = [2, 3]
>>> list1[slice(*args)]   # argument expansion
['c']
```

Comment: I see, the * before args is something called sequence unpacking which unpack the list into separate elements, so it's the same as slice(2,3), thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using List Comprehension or `operator.itemgetter`.

**List Comprehension**

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
indices = [2, 3]
result = [list1[i] for i in indices]
print(result)  # Output: ['c', 'd']
```

**operator.itemgetter**

```
from operator import itemgetter

list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
indices = [2, 3]
get_elements = itemgetter(*indices)
result = get_elements(list1)
print(result)  # Output: ('c', 'd')
```

**for the case: `itemgetter(*indices)(list1)`**

```
from operator import itemgetter

list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
indices = [2, 3]

result = itemgetter(*indices)(list1)
print(result)  # Output: ('c', 'd')
```

Comment: why not `result = itemgetter(*indices)(list1)`

Comment: @rioV8 yes you can do that too. 
I have modify the code. Please have a look.

Comment: It's a good way to choose separate elements! I thought a list could be a combination of multiple separate indices, so I can get the third and fourth element out of list1, but it didn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> *"Can't extract multiple elements from a Python list ..."*

Utilize the *[slice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice)* *built-in function*.

```py
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
b = a[(s := slice(2, 4))]
a[s] = []
```

Output

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'e']
b = ['c', 'd']
```

Comment: Wow, this is the first time I see :=, it's so neat, thanks!

Comment: @youhexuebiancheng, in _Python_, it is typically referred to as a, _"[named expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#assignment-expressions)"_.  Classically, this was the assignment operator used in most programming languages.  Not until the development of newer languages, such as _C_, was it simplified to just an _equal sign_; most subsequent languages followed suit.  Keep in mind, when using a _named expression_, you'll typically need to enclose it within parentheses.